# Paying more for an item -- Ribis?

Tags: transactions, gifts, lending-interest-ribbis

I will ask the question using the following scenario:

Reuvan wrote a sefer that he was charging for it 50 Shekels. Came along Shimon who wanted to buy the sefer. At that time he didn't have money on him so Reuvan agreed to give him the sefer now and that he could pay later. When Shimon came to pay a few days later he decided he wanted to give Reuvan a 100 shekels for the sefer instead of 50. His intention in giving it was to be for his (Reuvan's) benefit since he is a Talmud Chacham and wants to give him more for this sefer. Is there any problem of ribis with such a situation?

Comment: Is there a problem of interest with giving someone a gift?

Comment: Isn't ribis on the lender (or seller in your case). Not the giver/buyer?

Comment: @ba Even when it is meant as a gift, there could be a problem of *mechezei k'ribis*.

Comment: @Ariel It is forbidden for all parties (Bava Metzia 75b), and even if the *ribis* is only *d'rabbanan* the borrower still violates *lifnei iver*.

Answer (score 4):

There is a disagreement among the poskim, when there is a debt resulting from a purchase (chov machmas mekach) whether one may add extra payment at the time of the payment of the debt (if no condition was made before).

The Shach says that just as the Gemara states that if a purchaser prepaid for a purchase (rendering the payment a loan until the time of receipt of the product from the seller) the seller is allowed to add extra product at the time of delivery, so too may a buyer who owes money for product received add to the payment when payment is rendered.
Rabbi Akiva Eiger disagrees and limits the leniency of the Gemara to adding product to a prepaid sale, (PSIKA) but forbids adding payment to a purchase where the product was already given and the buyer owes the payment, (Tarsha).
See Yoreh Deah 161 -2 Rema - Shach and Hagahos R' akiva eiger.